# Socket.io, Electron JS and React Origin Security

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, electron

I'm making a game with Electron JS and React, standalone desktop application (I plan to distribute it on Steam), and since is a multiplayer online game, I'm setting the server in the cloud as well.
For the connection between client and server I'm using Socket.io in the next way:

```js
import express from "express";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { createServer } from 'node:http';

const port = process.env.PORT ?? 3000;

const app = express()
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    },
  });

io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
    console.log('a user has connected')

    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
        console.log('an user has disconnected')
    })
})

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>')
})

server.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

For now it works as intended, but I'm worried about the origin with * in the Server Side, since it will allow any connection to the server, so my question is, is it good to leave the cors origin with '*' or there are more secure approachs? Thanks for your help